# error in nnet.default when using mice: too many (1584) weights

Tags: r, r-mice

when I use `mice` to impute `NA`s, it gives me the following error:

> Error in nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  :
> too many (1584) weights

```r
library(mice)
imp <- mice(newdf)
```

I tried to modify `MaxNWts`, but I got the same error.

```r
imp <- mice(newdf,maxit = 5000,nnet.MaxNWts = 5000)
```

[image]

Can anyone help me with the problem? here is the screenshot of my data.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions should be reproducible. Please don’t use images of code or data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as `df <- data.frame(…)` where … are your variables and values or use `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I will reedit my question.